# TypeScriptで循環参照する定義を書く方法

Tags: typescript, 循環参照

Typescriptで以下のような定義をすると、

```
class A {
  public b: A.B
}

namespace A {
  class B {
  }
}
```

classAの定義で

`[ts] 名前空間 'A' にエクスポートされたメンバー 'B' がありません。`

と怒られるし、定義順を逆にするとclassBの定義で

`[ts] 名前空間宣言は、それとマージするクラスや関数より前に配置できません。`

と怒られるのですが、いい解決方法はありますか？

Answer (score 1):

当然ですが `B` を `export` すればエラーにはなりません。

```
class A {
    b: A.B

    constructor() {
        this.b = new A.B()
    }
}

namespace A {
    export class B {
        n = 123
    }
}
```

`B` を外部に露出したくないのだと思うのですが、その場合どうすればよいかは解りません。案として、`private static` な変数にクラス `B` を保持させ、宣言部でそれを使って初期化する方法を出しておきます。

```
class A {
    private static B = class B {
        n = 123
    }
    b = new A.B()
}
```